# Is it possible to create an app that can uploaded e-book files to a server and can delete downloaded files remotely?

Tags: pdf, cloud, epub, drm

I want to know if it's possible to create a system that can host epub or pdf files, allow users to download them, and then as an admin, I can remove their downloads whenever I want (for rental purposes).

This would bypass alot of major DRM solutions out there that are meant for large scale businesses and are expensive, but my needs are for a smaller organization. Maybe I can just build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do this - you'll see audio book applications like BorrowBox often have this functionality, as an example.

However, most such apps will also have some form of encryption as it is relatively easy to copy a downloaded file, which means users could simply copy your file before you revoke it at the end of the rental period.

Media security is usually about putting barriers in place to stop piracy - you need to balance the complexity and cost vs the potential loss or likelihood of someone trying to steal your content.

For some content, a system as you have described, maybe coupled with a simple encryption with the key transmitted out of band somehow or even built into the app, might be sufficient. For high value video content, like live sports etc, the owners typically consider it necessary to invest in 'higher or tougher barriers' and will use some form of secure key transfer in addition to encryption, which in the IP world usually means DRM.

Comment: How could I start learning more about the encryption process? I'm a web developer, so I know about encryption. Is there a platform or SDK that could allow for encryption of EPUBs and PDFs you know of?

Comment: If you actually want to understand encryption itself in depth there are a very good series of videos from a lecturer in Germany on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1usFRN4LCMcfIV7UjHNuQg For tools to encrypt PDF, Adobe actually has some API's which might be a good starting point to look at: https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-64/forms/developer-reference/programming-aem-forms-jee/performing-service-operations-using-apis/encrypting-decrypting-pdf-documents.html